# Transfer data from vector<unsigned char> to unsigned char[]

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a function that return a vector of bytes (unsigned chars). How can I get that data into an array. Apparently the vector is contiguous virtual memory, so that should be easy. I have tried doing this

```
std::vector<unsigned char> a;
unsigned char* b = &a[0];
```

but I have not had any luck.

My code looks something like this

```
// 20 is length of returned vector
const int SOME_LENGTH = 20;
vector<unsigned char> a = get_some_bytes(SOME_LENGTH);
unsigned char b[SOME_LENGTH];
b = &a;
```

But I am getting this error

> ```
> error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘std::vector<unsigned
> char>*’ to ‘unsigned char [20]’
> ```

Comment: What the linked to answer proposes and what you did are as different as night and day.

Comment: `unsigned char b[a.size()];` VLAs are a non-standard C++ extension.

Comment: @StoryTeller how? hes pointing the memory location of one double to the start of the vector. I want to point the memory location of the first of a contiguous set of unsigned chars to the first memory location in the vector

Comment: Which is precisely what you are not doing. You don't declare a pointer, you declare an array (by extension). And the address of the vector is not the same thing as the address of the buffer it manages.

Comment: @Borgleader you are saying since a.size() is not constant int, that allocation will not work? Either way, in my actual code, I have a constant int set to the number that goes into both the function and the buffer allocation. I will update my code

Comment: Scrolling down to at least the second answer would have helped. :/

Comment: Also, it seems like you are lacking knowledge about some core concepts of C++. Reading a good C++ book sounds like a productive idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply copy bytes from the vector's data to your array:

```
std::copy(begin(a), end(a), b);
```

Note though you could directly use [`a.data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)(no copy needed) in lieu of `b` almost everywhere.

Comment: Plus your definition of `b` involves VLA which are not standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

You cant initialize array like that.
You have to use pointers.

Here is a simple solution.
If you know the size you can do this:

```
const size_t SIZE = 5000; // for example
unsigned char b[SIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    b[i] = a[i];
```

But if you don't know the size, then you have to use the `new` operator

```
unsigned char * b = new unsigned[a.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
   b[i] = a[i];
```

**Edit**

In your case you can do this:

```
vector<unsigned char> a = get_some_bytes(SOME_LENGTH);
unsigned char * b = &a[0];
```